# ofstream is writing date and time only

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I am trying to write to text file but after my code executes I can only see the time and date written in my file rather than the actual data that I need written into the file.

What is strange is when I run program I can see the data stored in memory until I close the windows console but its not storing the data into a file.

I have code that uses the ifstream and has close at the end so I am not sure if that might be keeping the file open. Also when I am writing to file my program writes at the last position of the cursor rather than end of the file. Here my code to write to the file.

```
void createPerson (Person persons[], int* count) {
    char fullName[100];
    char personAddress[200];
    int Marks1;
    int Marks2;
    int Marks3;
    int Marks4;
    int Marks5;
    int personNumber;
    string personGender;

    ofstream outfile("testFile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
 if(outfile.fail()){
  cerr << "File cannot be opened" << endl;
  }

    cout<<"Enter the person's number: "<<endl;
    cin>>personNumber;
    cout <<"Enter the person's Full name: "<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(fullName,50);
    cout<<"Enter the score for Marks1: "<<endl;
    cin>>Marks1;
    cout<<"Enter the score for Marks2: "<<endl;
    cin>>Marks2;
    cout<<"Enter the score for Marks3: "<<endl;
    cin>>Marks3;
    cout<<"Enter the score for Marks4: "<<endl;
    cin>>Marks4;
    cout<<"Enter the score for Marks5: "<<endl;
    cin>>Marks5;    
    cout<<"Enter the person's address: "<<endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(personAddress,50);
    cout<<"Enter the person's sex: "<<endl;
    cin>>personGender;

    persons[*count] = person(personNumber,fullName, 
        Marks1,Marks2, Marks3, Marks4, Marks5,
         personAddress, personGender);
    (*count)++;

    outfile << persons[*count].getpersonNumber()<<":";
 outfile << persons[*count].getpersonName()<<":"; 
 outfile << persons[*count].getMarks1()<<":";
 outfile << persons[*count].getMarks2()<<":";
 outfile << persons[*count].getMarks3()<<":";
 outfile << persons[*count].getMarks4()<<":";
 outfile << persons[*count].getMarks5()<<":\n";
 outfile << persons[*count].getPersonAddress()<<":";
 outfile << persons[*count].getPersonGender();

 outfile.close();

    cout << persons[*count].getPersonName();
}
```

Comment: Why do you use arrays for everything but the `Marks`?  Your program would be a lot simpler if you had an array of `Marks`.

Comment: Why is `createPerson` outside the scope of the `Person` class?  All the data members you need to initialize are in the class, so this function should be there as well.

Comment: Pass the variable `count` by reference, so you don't have pointer issues.

Comment: I recommend that you use the debugger, place a breakpoint where you increment `count` and verify that the `persons` array has correct information.

Comment: Perhaps your attempts to write to your output file should be before you increment your `count` variable...

Comment: I think the array is ok because the data is being stored into the buffer/freestore and it is there when I run my printRecord() method. The problem is when I go to the text file the only change on the file is just a date and time eg. 21:37 05/12/2014. Also when I exit the program all the data is lost except the one previously saved on the file as well as the time and date (which I do not need)

Comment: I agree with @twalberg that the `count` increment looks suspect -- assuming this functions name expresses its intent, why would you attempt to output a person that has not yet been created?  As written, the person at the next array index would already have to exist -- otherwise, who knows what the memory contains.